# using pie func in python in vscode jupyter notebook

Tags: python

```
#TypeError: pie() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
from cProfile import label
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
d=[75,20,1,2]
l=['n2','o2','c','other']
c=['red','black','blue','green']
plt.pie(data=d,labels=l,colors=c)
plt.title('air comp')
plt.show()
```

It's showing error when I use pie function. I tried to run it on vscode jupyter notebook extension.

Comment: what is the error? edit your question to include the full error information please

Comment: `plt.pie(d, labels=l, colors=c)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.